# How can I enrich in viur relations with further data fields

Tags: python, viur

How can I enrich in viur relations with further data fields.

With SQL Alchemy I can do this with Association Objects.
Is this also possible in viur?

I have tried the following:

```
skeleton.relation.setBoneValue(skeleton, "relation", {"key":keyObj,"afield":"avalue}, True)
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the third parameter of the setBoneValue function must be a tuple containing the keyObj as the first value and a RelSkel as the second value.

So the correct way looks like this:

```
class exampleRelSkel(RelSkel):
  afield= stringBone(descr="a Field Description")

myRelSkel = exampleRelSkel()
myRelSkel["afield"] = "avalue" #set the value

skeleton.relation.setBoneValue(skeleton, "relation",(keyObj,myRelSkel),True)
```